# Datastream bigquery_profile is empty

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-datastream

I am trying to create Datastream with terraform according to the Google Cloud official blog [1]. There, `bigquery_profile`  is empty. Is it okay?
When I check the official documentation[2], the bigqueryprofile section is also empty.

```
resource "google_datastream_connection_profile" "destination" {
    display_name          = "BigQuery Destination"
    location              = "us-central1"
    connection_profile_id = "destination"

    bigquery_profile {}
}
```

[1] https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/replicating-postgres-data-to-bigquery?hl=en
[2] https://cloud.google.com/datastream/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.connectionProfiles#bigqueryprofile

Comment: Does this [link](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/datastream_connection_profile) help you?

Comment: I already checked the documentation but it does not explain ‘bigquery_profile’.